# What should the site be called / named?

Tags: discussion, design

A couple of StackExchange sites have clever names, e.g.:

- AskDifferent (apple.stackexchange.com)
- Seasoned Advice (cooking.stackexchange.com)

"Science Fiction & Fantasy" is a bit of a mouthful, and doesn't work well in conversation ("I'll ask on scifi dot stackexchange") since it's a generic term.

Is there interest in selecting a name for the site?  If you've got a good idea about what it could be, please suggest in an answer.

I think (and wasn't corrected in chat) that this is part of the site design, and so the name doesn't have to be exactly the Area51 description, even though it is in most cases.  (It's possible that cooking & apple are special cases, because they date from the time when there was going to be a completely separate brand for each site, rather than using the StackExchange umbrella, but I can't find that stated anywhere).

Note that this is not about the URL, which will always remain scifi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I thought of abbreviating it to **sci-fi-fan**! But that has another meaning...

Comment: Site names were originally part of the site's identity, but that turned out to be a mistake: see [Joel's blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/) and the [branding announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443). Now the idea is that sites can get clever names (e.g. [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/), but [can stick with the default](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [aren't forced to accept a mediocre name such as “Nothing To Install”](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The official successor to naming is the [elevator pitch](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-is-scifi-ses-elevator-pitch) — see [Robert Cartaino's elevator pitch pitch](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/). But most sites haven't been able to come up with anything nearing a good pitch.

Comment: I just posted about the site, and I found myself fumbling for clear phrasing - "I've posted this at 'Science Fiction and Fantasy'" doesn't work too nicely when you're posting on the forums of F&SF magazine... or any other genre-oriented forum, really. "SF&F.SE" is fine for within the network, but it's pretty oblique for promotional purposes.

Answer (score 7):

**We should stick with "Science Fiction & Fantasy"**

The generic name works for sites like photography.stackexchange.com and electronics.stackexchange.com ("Electronics Design"), so can work for us.

Comment: Provided as a means to vote no, since some people don't like using a question down-vote for that purpose, even in meta.

Comment: and the abbreviation "scifi.se" in conversation works well enough too

Comment: SF&F SE for short. Sci-fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange works fine for the long name. I think any imaginative variation from the names of the genres will lead to confusion.

Comment: Well, [I don't like the current name much](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/565/what-should-our-site-name-be), but I don't have a better proposal at this time.

Comment: @Gilles exactly my feeling :)

Comment: This is clear for our own use, but for promotional purposes, it doesn't work too well. Telling SF&F fans "Come to our site, SF&F!" is... odd. (Not, of course, that I've a better suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the "tagline" or "elevator pitch" which is optional, but can be incorporated into the design.

> Give us the one sentence “elevator pitch” for your community. How would you explain your site to a stranger you met on an elevator? It’s about … what, exactly?

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/

Answer (score -1):

Continuing with @pearsonartphoto's suggestion, I would suggest "the oracle". It is a trope in fantasy and also popular in sci-fi (thanks to the matrix), plus it also refers to the question and answer aspect of the site.

Answer (score -2):

I'm thinking something like "The Wizard's Ship", or maybe "The Flying Dragon". I don't quite like either, but I'll toss it in to encourage creativity.