# What should our site name be?

Tags: discussion, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should the site be called?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/what-should-the-site-be-called)

Our site's official name is now “Science Fiction & Fantasy”. That's quite a mouthful, and it doesn't even convey the site's topic that well — on the surface it includes alternate history, horror, slipstream.

“[Speculative fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction)” would be a more accurate description, but it's not a well-known phrase, even amongst SF aficionados.

“Sci-fi”, the original name, is nice and short, but seems to exclude fantasy and other SF subgenres. It also evokes [B-grade science fiction only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-fi#Definitions) to some people, so that's no good.

SFF, the current abbreviation, is not very telling: SF is a commonly-accepted abbreviation for science-fiction or speculative fiction, but SFF receives blank looks. Unfortunately, in a Stack Exchange context, “SF” evokes [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), so there's potential for confusion here too.

Is there a better name for the site?

*Note that this isn't about a domain name. The domain name would remain `something.stackexchange.com`, possibly with aliases. This is about what visitors would see in big type on the front page, and about how we'd encourage people to mention the site.*

<sub>What other Stack Exchange are doing: most are called “something” Stack Exchange, but with a single-word “something”. A few have an extra name, e.g. [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is officially [Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/design-for-the-apple-stackexchange-site). [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/) is formally “Engish Language & Usage”, but “English” in a Stack Exchange site name context works. [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) can be abbreviated “DIY”.</sub>

Comment: It's best to keep these discussions and suggestions about a site name in one thread... asked virtually identically: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/474/what-should-the-site-be-called