# Closing as duplicate and merging should bump the question's "activeness"

Tags: feature-request

A [question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/565/what-should-our-site-name-be) was recently asked that was a duplicate of [another](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/what-should-the-site-be-called) because the asker missed the original when searching.  The duplicate was closed (and I think merged, since answers to the duplicate are now in the original, but I don't really know how merging works).

However, the original question is on the third page of active questions (because it's reasonably old).  It seems like opening a duplicate question and/or merging a question should make it active in the same way that editing or answering it would.

(The closed question is still high in the active list, but people tend to ignore the closed questions).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior seems right to me. Usually, when a question is closed as a duplicate, the older question has had reasonable answers and can be left to rest. Occasionally the two duplicates were posted at very close times, so one will still be active. Occasionally the closed question has had valuable answers which a moderator merged into the old one, but even then there's no particular reason to bring more attention to the old question.

This was a very unusual case: a meta question which was meant to remain current for a long time. Even then, I don't see a reason to bring particular attention to the old question now. An edit to the old question will bring it back on the front page if needed.

I did merge the answers, by the way. Both questions had a “keep the current name” answer which happened to have the same number of votes, so I deleted one.